# Converting Linear Motion into rotary motion

Tags: linear-motion

I'm looking at designing something using the same mechanism used in this pepper grinder. As far as my knowledge goes, it is converting vertical Linear motion (the push button) into horizontal rotary motion (the ceramic grinder).[image: .] 
I would like to understand how this is achieved, especially in such a small vessel.
I'm an amateur when it comes to this stuff, and was hoping someone here could explain it to me.
I appreciate all answers.
Thanks, Beau

Comment: Hi, have you heard something about linear actuators? there are tons of ways that convert linear to rotary motion, take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ziGR9ggO60), if you still have questions then we are here.

Comment: Suggested a simple device called a cam, but obviously that was not liked by a downvoter...

Answer (score 2):

This is a diagram for the mechanism, [image: linear actuator].

And here is Wikipedia link, [click](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_actuator).

Comment: Linear actuators convert rotary to linear - the question is about linear to rotary. There is no electric motor here...

Comment: The mechanism remains the same, if you push or pull the shaft you can make the rotor to rotate.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, they've been a real help!

Comment: Yes and no - pushing a linear actuator will not cause a rotation because the pitch of the lead screw is too shallow.

Answer (score -1):

Universal joint and threaded rods on each end of U Joint or a ring gear and pinion with threaded rods on each

Comment: Could you add more information to your post? As it stands now, it is either a comment or could use more explanation.